# Use custom font issue

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I have a custom font file that i want to use on my application , currently i am using .net framework2 and here is the code i used :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //load the resource
    Stream fontStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Eurostile_Regular_0.ttf");

    //create an unsafe memory block for the data
    System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Convert.ToInt16(fontStream.Length));

    //create a buffer to read in to
    byte[] fontdata = null;
    fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length + 1];

    //fetch the font program from the resource
    fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, Convert.ToInt16(fontStream.Length));

    //copy the bytes to the unsafe memory block
    Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, Convert.ToInt16(fontStream.Length));

    //pass the font to the font collection
    pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, Convert.ToInt16(fontStream.Length));

    //close the resource stream
    fontStream.Close();

    //free the unsafe memory
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
}
```

And on Form1_Paint :

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    bool bold = false;
    bool regular = false;
    bool italic = false;

    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;

    SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    float y = 5;

    System.Drawing.Font fn;

    foreach (FontFamily ff in pfc.Families)
    {
        if (ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
        {
            regular = true;
            fn = new Font(ff, 18, FontStyle.Regular);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name, fn, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            fn.Dispose();
            y += 20;
        }

        if (ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Bold))
        {
            bold = true;
            fn = new Font(ff, 18, FontStyle.Bold);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name, fn, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            fn.Dispose();
            y += 20;
        }

        if (ff.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Italic))
        {
            italic = true;
            fn = new Font(ff, 18, FontStyle.Italic);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name, fn, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            fn.Dispose();
            y += 20;
        }

        if (bold && italic)
        {
            fn = new Font(ff, 18, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name, fn, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            fn.Dispose();
            y += 20;
        }
        fn = new Font(ff, 18, FontStyle.Underline);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name, fn, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        fn.Dispose();
        y += 20;
        fn = new Font(ff, 18, FontStyle.Strikeout);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(fn.Name, fn, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        fn.Dispose();
    }
    b.Dispose();
}
```

But the font is not working and i get a JIT error from the second line on form_load

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The error is probably because fontStream is null meaning you are not successfully loading it from your resources.  The name you are using is probably incorrect in some way.

Answer (score 1):

First go to your `Font Properties` -> `Build Action` -> `"Embedded Resource"`

Second your problem is that you forgot to add your NameSpace name in the code

**Wrong format**

```
Stream fontStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FileName.ttf");
```

**Correct format**

```
Stream fontStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("NameSpaceName.FileName.ttf");
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The fontStream is null because GetManifestResourceStream could not find your font.  Your font has to be added to the solution and then choosing "embedded resource" in the properties under build action.  It looks like you may have tried to embed the font but haven't correctly named it in your stream request.  Adding your project resource collection:

```
Stream fontStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourApp.Eurostile_Regular_0.ttf");
```

You can get further information here: [How to embed a True Type Font](https://web.archive.org/web/20141224204810/http://bobpowell.net/embedfonts.aspx)